# Parse get multiple objects using their objectIds

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a `ArrayList<String>` -named `listObjectId` below- of objectIds. I'm trying to get all the objects that have an `objectId` contained in the `ArrayList`.

The solution I have right now, I think, is very bad from a performance point of view:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listObjectId.size(); i++) {
    ItemModel mItemModelRetrieved = null;
    ParseQuery<ItemModel > query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ItemModel .class);

    try {
        mItemModelRetrieved = query.get(listObjectId.get(i));
        subscriber.onNext(mItemModelRetrieved ); //-- I'm using RxJava
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error Local " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. You have the object ids, so create a ParseObject with them using `ParseObject.createWithoutData` and then fetch the object. Try the following:

```
List<ParseObject> parseObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (String objectId : listObjectId) {
    parseObjects.add(ParseObject.createWithoutData(ItemModel.class, objectId));
}

ParseObject.fetchAll(parseObjects);
// parseObjects will now contain all data retrieved from Parse.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting tells you that the data type of the column you query must be of type Array, not the value you pass into the method.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question. I think my solution is not great, do you see a better way to retrieve a list of objects ?